# How can I compare two select menus with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

I have two select menus and I want to compare them. If I choose the first select options, I want to disable option which has same name in second select menu. How can I do this with only using JavaScript? And also I want to write to p element all selected options values from both side.

```html
<form>
  <select multiple class="form-control" id="f144" onchange="">
      <option>REAR CASE</option>
      <option>CASE ASSEMBLY</option>
      <option>POLE CLAMP ASS</option>
      <option>POLE CLAMP KNOB</option>
      <option>COVER PERIPHERAL</option>
      <option>RETAINER CORD</option>
  </select>
</form>
<form>
  <select multiple class="form-control" for="fvisual" onchange="">
      <option>CASE ASSEMBLY</option>
      <option>FRONT CASE</option>
      <option>REAR CASE</option>
      <option>ASM DOOR</option>
      <option>SHIELD</option>
      <option>KEYPAD</option>
      <option>DISPLAY</option>
      <option>HANDLE DOOR</option>
      <option>RETAINER CORD</option>
      <option>POLE CLAMP ASS</option>
      <option>POLE CLAMP KNOB</option>
      <option>COVER PERIPHERAL</option>
  </select>
</form>
<p id="p1"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's my answer. I've compared two selection menus and I've disabled the options I want. But there's still something I want to do. I want to do, which option is selected deselection when I click a second time. But the solution in my mind didn't work.

```js
var a = document.f1.s1;
var b = document.f2.s1;
var array = [false, false, false, false];
function disable() {
    for (i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        if (a[i].selected && array[i] == false) {
            for (j = 0; j < b.length; j++) {
              if (a[i].value == b[j].value) {
                b[j].setAttribute("disabled", true);
              }
            }
            array[i] = true;
        }
        else if (a[i].selected && array[i] == true) {
          a[i].selected = false;
          array[i] = false;
        }
    }
}
```

```html
<form name="f1">
  <select name="s1" multiple onchange="disable()">
    <option>ABCDE</option>
    <option>BCDEF</option>
    <option>CDEFG</option>
    <option>DEFGH</option>
  </select>
</form>
<form name="f2">
  <select name="s1" multiple>
    <option>ABCDE</option>
    <option>BCDEF</option>
    <option>CDEFG</option>
    <option>DEFGH</option>
  </select>
</form>
```